# Find all reall numbers $A$, $w$ and $\delta$ such that $\sin t+\cos t=A\sin(\omega t+\delta)$, for all $t$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need help with this exercise.

Find all reall numbers $A$, $w$ and $\delta$ such that $\sin t+\cos t=A\sin(\omega t+\delta)$, for all $t$.

I really don't have a clue where to start. I will appreciate any hint that helps me to start working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by recognizing that

$$\sin t + \cos t = \sqrt2 \left(\sin t \cos \frac{\pi}4 + \cos t \sin \frac{\pi}4\right) = \sqrt2 \sin \left(t + \frac{\pi}4\right)$$

Now what can we say about $A$, $\omega$, and $\delta$?

Comment: So $A=\sqrt{2}$, $\omega =1$ and $\delta = \frac{\pi}{4}$??? But $\sin t+\cos t=\sqrt{2} (\sin t \cos \frac{\pi}{4}+ \cos t \sin \frac{\pi}{4})$ is an identity? Sorry... but never see/heard before of it.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. For example, we could also take $A = -\sqrt 2$, $\omega = -1$, and $\delta = \frac{7\pi}{4}$. Try investigating what the graph of the function $A\sin(\omega t + \delta)$ looks like as you change the values of $A$, $\omega$, and $\delta$, and compare that to $\sqrt2\sin(t + \frac{\pi}4)$.

Comment: As for the equation, it's just using the fact that $\cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \sin \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: So $\delta$ would be $\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k$ (where $k$ is an integer) when $A=\sqrt{2}$ and $\omega =1$? And $\delta$ also would be $\frac{7\pi}{4}+2\pi k$ when $A=-\sqrt{2}$ and $\omega =-1$.

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! <3